# Why is wrapper.findComponent not working for @vue/test-utils

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

When I try using `wrapper.findComponent`, I get the following error:

> ErrorWrapper { selector: { ref: 'loginTab' } }

I have searched online but to no avail. Here is my test code:

```
describe('Sign-Up Test Cases', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(SignUp, {
        methods: {
            getProv: jest.fn()
        },
        localVue
    })
    
    it('Dialog contains a Login Input Field', () => {
        console.log(wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'loginTab' }))
        expect(wrapper.findComponent({ ref: 'loginTab' }))
    })
})
```

`localVue` is already defined.
Check the `it` statement where I am using the `findComponent` function.

**UPDATE: Something else I tried.**

I tried this and it didn't work.

```
import Vuetify, {VTab} from 'vuetify/lib'
// Some Code here
console.log(wrapper.findComponent(VTab))
```

and it didn't work. I got the following error:

```
ErrorWrapper {selector: [Function: VueComponent]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the component and use it as payload for the `findComponent` method:

```
const VTab = {
   template: '<div><slot></div>
}

const wrapper = shallowMount(SignUp, {
        global: {
           stubs: { VTab }
        },
    })

wrapper.findComponent(VTab)
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. ```import Vuetify, {VTab} from 'vuetify/lib' ``` and ```console.log(wrapper.findComponent(VTab))``` and it didn't work. I got the following error: ```ErrorWrapper {selector: [Function: VueComponent]}```

Comment: If it's a component from vuetify, you have to stub the component. I change my answer

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: can you explain more your problem ?